# Using str_word_count to count letters within the opponent word

Tags: php, string

user 1 writes a word (word1) and I want to count how many letters of the word1 there are within the opponent word (word2).
At first I used the `strpos` function but it doesn't seem to count reppeated letters so I change to the `str_word_count` function but no matter what the word1 is the `countex` is always 5
This is my code:

```
 for($i=0;$i<10 && ($rowword=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ;$i++){

    $aword1 = str_split($rowword['word']);
     $word2=$row['word2']; //$row comes from another query that gets the word of the opponent
     $countex=0;

        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
            $currentletter=$aword1[$i];

            if(str_word_count($word2,0,$currentletter)){
                $countex++;
            }    
        }

 } //end of outter for
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Example of what I want to achieve:

word2=annoy, word1=again
in this example `countex` should be 2 because in the word "again" the letter "a" and "n" exist in the word "annoy"

Comment: What a result do you expect if any letter is present some times in a word? May be, you show some examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how many letters are in both words then you can use this code:

```
$lettersFromWord1 = str_split ($word1);
$lettersFromWord2 = str_split ($word2);

$matches  = 0;
foreach($lettersFromWord1 as $letter){
    if ( in_array($letter, $lettersFromWord2)){
        $matches++;
    }
}

echo "Word: " . $word1 . " and Word: " . $word2 . " has " . $matches . " matching letters";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_split` aswell as `strpos` for that:

https://3v4l.org/7ogrE

```
<?php

$word1 = 'abcdefghijkl';
$word2 = 'acgikluuo';
$expected = 6;

function countMatchingChars($word1, $word2) {
    $matching = 0;
    foreach(str_split($word1) as $char) {
        if(strpos($word2, $char) !== false) {
            $matching++;
        }
    }

    return $matching;
}

$matchingChars = countMatchingChars($word1, $word2);

assert($matchingChars === $expected);
```

References:

http://php.net/str_split

http://php.net/strpos